# Rails how to pass object between methods

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid

Everyone! I have a view `show` which displaying links for files  that can be downloaded. I have a method - `download_file` which sends the file

```
def download_file
@myfile = Myfile.find(params[:myfile]) <======this line does not work
    send_file Rails.root.join(@myfile.myfile_directory,  "file.csv"),  :type=>"application/csv", :x_sendfile=>true
    flash[:notice] = "Your file has been downloaded" 
end
```

My question is - How can I pass Myfile object to controller `download_file` method from view `show`? 
My view

```
<td><%= @myfile.myfile_name %></td>
  <%= link_to "Download file" , :action => 'download_file' %>
<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_myfile_path(@myfile) %>
```

I have tried in controller:

```
@myfile = Myfile.find(params[:myfile])
@myfile = Myfile.find(params[:myfile]).first
@myfile = Myfile.find(params[:id])
 @myfile = Myfile.find(params[:id]).first
```

It does not work. 
Thank you very much for help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `routes.rb` you need

```
resources :myfiles do
  member do 
    get :download_file
  end
end
```

Then, within your view `<%= link_to "Download file" , download_file_my_file_path(@myfile) %>`. For the route name, check the output of `rake routes` for the correct path name, cause I may be mistaken.

Comment: Hi! Thank you for helping! I tried it and getting error, `undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass`

Comment: And it throws from...?

Comment: Just found out `download_file_my_files_path(:id =>@myfile.id)` works fine!